# True replicates or nested data ANOVA - only one experimental unit per condition

Tags: r, anova, experiment-design, nested-data, fractional-factorial

I'm in materials science. I have a fractional factorial experiment. I am investigating the main effect of various treatments on a measured response.  The exact details are probably not needed to understand my question so I will simplify things in order to frame my question a more straight forward way (I have 7 factors, but lets just consider 2).

The problem I have is that my replicates are not true replicates, for each set of measurements (with factors set at defined levels) I am only able to make a single batch of material.  I then produce individual specimens from that particular batch for testing (say 10 individuals from a batch).

I am aware that the variation *within* a particular batch is lower than the variation *between* batches when the treatment factors are kept constant. Nevertheless, economic reasons prevent me from making multiple batches of materials for all cases.

If I ignore this fact and run an ANOVA in R my p-values suggest that the treatment factors have significance than I suspect they really have. I'm using R for the analysis and at the moment I am using something like:

```
 anova = aov(Response ~ TreatmentA * TreatmentB, data=dataframe)
```

As a separate experiment I have done some complete replications, e.g. 3 different batches with 10 specimens tested from each batch and not changed the treatment factors.  This gives me an indication of batch-to-batch variability.

Is there a way I can plug results of this second experiment as some sort of additional error factor into my first experiment?

As I said, I'm sure the answer to the question is out there but I might be struggling to find the right search term.

Comment: Is there a reason to believe that batch-to-batch variability will be the same in all conditions (at all combinations of treatment factors)? Are you willing to make this assumption?

Comment: @amoeba Thanks for the response.  
Good point, it is quite possible that it won't be the same.  Some of the treatment factors could potentially increase the variability. I think that the particular set of conditions I chose for the repeats are likely to be among the worst in terms of variability.

Is there any other way I could approach this other than making making that assumption? 

I would prefer to fail to identify a significant factor than to label something as significant that isn't. 

The experiment is intended to be a screening exercise in order to guide the next steps.

Comment: It's an interesting problem. You said you have 7 factors - that's a lot of factors! Even if all of them are binary, this means 2^7 = 128 batches to cover all combinations of levels; if some factors have more than 2 levels then it's even more. Correct?

Comment: @amoeba I do have 7 factors and they are all binary.  However it is a fractional factorial 2^(7-3) resolution IV design. http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section3/eqns/2to7m3.txt

So I have 16 runs total.  All my 2-way interactions are confounded with 2 others.  I've tried to separate the most likely interactions.  Therefore I'm looking for main effects and evidence of interactions. 

The idea is a more specific follow up study is then envisioned.